# Upload image/longblob to mysql database using stored procedure,php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

> I am attempting to upload a image to my database, i know it is bad practice to upload images to the database. I have it working by running the query in my php class (DB Handler). Now I am attempting to use a stored procedure and can't seem to find my error in my stored procedure. Apologies if my question seems vague.

## DB Handler.php

```
public static function Business_Logo_Upload($image)
    {
        $sp = 'CALL uspBusines_Logo_Upload(?)';
        return DBHelper::BlobUpload($sp,$image);
    }
```

## DBHelper.php

```
public static function BlobUpload($query,$image)
    {
        //Open Connection
        $conn = DB::Connect();
        //Prepare Query
        $call = $conn->prepare($query);
        $null = null;
        $call->bind_param('b', $null);
        $call->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($image));
        $call->execute();
        //Close Connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
        //Return Result
        return $call;
    }
```

## MYSQL Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`BIT1`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspBusines_Logo_Upload`(IN logo LONGBLOB)
BEGIN
    DECLARE errno INT;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    GET CURRENT DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;
    SELECT errno AS MYSQL_ERROR;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SET autocommit=0;

    UPDATE business
    SET business.Logo = logo
    WHERE business.BusinessID = 1;
END
```

Comment: `business.Logo` will be interpreted as a single column since you have it between back ticks.Same below.

Comment: Presumably this is PHP? If so, please tag your question accordingly. What happens when you run the code - do you get error messages?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt apologies for the wrong tag. I do not get any errors.

Comment: This is the result if it succeeds or fails {affected_rows: null, insert_id: null, num_rows: null, param_count: null, field_count: null,…}

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`BIT1`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspBusines_Logo_Upload`(IN logo LONGBLOB)
BEGIN
    UPDATE business
    SET business.Logo = logo
    WHERE business.BusinessID = 1;
END
```

> This is the solution. Had to remove the transaction.